# Use a macro to highlight cells with a background colour

Tags: excel, vba, fill

I need my macro to delete rows containing a red cell.

I started by sorting the column containing red cells so that blank cells were at the top, then manually clicked the top red cell (row 100) and highlighted the rest using Ctrl-Shift-Down. As such, part of my code looks like this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 _
    Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],[First Name]]"), SortOn:= _
    xlSortOnCellColor, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB _
    (255, 0, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
Rows("100:150").Select
```

How can I amend the last part so that my macro *detects* the red cells *then* highlights them, so that it'll work regardless of how many cells I have in my sheet?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't sort, just filter and then delete the `VisibleCells`.

Comment: Or, if you do not like filtering,  read the page that Microsoft created on this subject: [How to select cells/ranges by using Visual Basic procedures in Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/select-cells-rangs-with-visual-basic)

Comment: Have you tried the suggested answer yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should give you what you want.  Uses `AutoFilter` by cell color & deletes en masse.  Let me know how you go with it.

```
Option Explicit
Sub DeleteByColor()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws.ListObjects("Table1").Range
    .AutoFilter 1, RGB(255, 0, 0), 8
    .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).EntireRow.Delete
    .AutoFilter
End With

End Sub
```